# 'var' is not defined as internal or external command in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install histogramjs package. `npm i histogramjs` --->works well but when I try to run -->  `var hist = require('histogramjs')`
I got the error on cmd:

```
'var' is not defined as internal or external command in npm
```

I have tried already tried 
`npm install var`  -- >get installed abd when I try to run ---> `var env = require('var');`

get the same error..

If run directly from node.js , get error `'cannot find module 'var'`

Please help as I am very new to npm and node
Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to run `var hist = require('histogramjs')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not type in `var hist ....` in your command line. What you type there, will be executed by shell, not by npm/node.

Instead, try:

1. Run `npm init`. Press enter couple of times, until it completes. This will create `package.json` file which is npm's configuration file. this file will tell npm, among others, which file is an entry point to your application.
2. Edit `package.json`, add `"start": "node app.js",` inside `"scripts"` element (see example below).
3. Create `app.js` in the same directory where `package.json` is located. Put your script in this file.
4. Run `npm start`.

If your script depends on 3rd party modules (in your case - "histogramjs" probably), install those as well:

```
npm install --save histogramjs
```

Running it without `--save` modifier will work as well. But `--save` will cause npm to put "histogramjs" as a dependency in package.json. Thanks to that, when someone gets your code later (i.e. from repository), he'll be able to simply run `npm install`, without even having to care which dependencies are required.

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "t",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD"
}
```

**app.js**

```
var hist = require('histogramjs')
// ... rest of your code
```